# Sequelize: use $like on JSON data type with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) with PostgreSQL.

I need to build a destroy query that can use the `$like` operator on a JSON data type.

For example, let's take this model definition:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

var Project = sequelize.define('project', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  details: {
    type: Sequelize.JSON,
    defaultValue: {}
  },
});
```

Now, I would like to be able to run a query to destroy all Project entries that don't have any details:

```
Project.destroy({
  where: {
    details: {
      $like: '{}'
    }
  }
})
```

But I get this error:

```
[SequelizeDatabaseError: operator does not exist: json ~~ unknown]
```

So, is there any way to do this and how?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$like: { $any: ['cat', 'hat']} // LIKE ANY ARRAY['cat', 'hat'] - also works for iLike and notLike
```

From [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/).